# How to get the last seven days data from mysql details in brief

Tags: php, mysql

Actually I have a table which name is posts and another table which name is newscount , in posts table there is four column id , title ,details, postingDate 
and in newscount table there is three column which are id, postid, count , 
and in newscount table postid is the id of posts table id , I have saved data in posts table and also i have data in newscount table , for example - in posts table I have

```
id title details postingDate
 1,title1,details1,somedate1 
 2,title2,details2,somedate2 
 3,title3,details3,somedate3
```

and in newscount table I have

```
id=1,postid=1,count=6 

id=2,postid=2,count=5 

id=3,postid=3,count=7
```

I want to select last two data from posts table which have maximum count , like if i select then it should show result like newscount.id=3,posts.id=3 which has max 7 count and newcount.id=1,posts.id=1 and its details 
I have tried but it is showing only postsid 3detials not last two

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT newscount.postId, newscount.count from newscount WHERE newscount.count = (SELECT max(count) FROM newscount ORDER BY id LIMIT 2) ) tempcounts INNER JOIN posts ON posts.id = tempcounts.postId WHERE posts.isActive=1 AND posts.postingDate >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY AND posts.postingDate < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY  ORDER BY posts.postingDate DESC limit 2
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't run your query because you didn't give a complete table structure of your db, but you have at least 2 item to make them correct:
first:

you have this query, but it does not return two parameters(except in condition you have more than one row with max value)

```
(SELECT max(count) FROM newscount ORDER BY id LIMIT 2)
```

instead of that use this:

```
(SELECT count FROM newscount ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 2)
```

the second: if you expect to get more than 1 row from a subquery in where clause you should use `in` instead of `=` operand